# How to revive a prior Windows install?

Tags: windows, bios, license

Disclaimer: I'm not sure if this is the correct Stack Exchange site to ask this question. I am asking it here because of [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209397/where-do-i-ask-questions-about-the-windows-os).

I have a notebook which originally came factory-installed with a version of Windows 8. Then one day Microsoft offered me the chance to update to Windows 10, which I did. Sometime after, while updating the OS, it crashed. I got mad with Microsoft and installed Ubuntu 18. It's been a few years since then, and now I want to use this notebook to play games and code with Visual Studio. **I want to install Windows on it again.**  I have two questions related to this issue:

1. Is there a way for me to recover my license and know if it still valid? I was told that the Windows key should still be in the BIOS.
2. Assuming the key is there, would I need to first install Windows 8 and then wait for Microsoft to ask me to update to Windows 10?

Comment: You wrote "Microsoft offered me the chance to update to Windows 10 and I got it."  So as we have both noted, you already have a legal license.

Comment: To build on @Ramhound's answer, as you're intermingling Product Key and License: PCs that took the free upgrade were upgraded with a generic Product Key _(i.e. everyone with Home or Pro used the same respective Product Key)_, and once Windows Update was run following the Win10 upgrade, a unique digital license for Windows 10 was saved to the user's Microsoft account, tied to the motherboard's hardware ID _(i.e. if the motherboard is ever replaced, you'll need to deactivate the license for that motherboard either via the Microsoft account device's page or via calling Microsoft)_.

Comment: FYI: Since you'll be clean installing Win10, ensure you download the CPU-related drivers (Chipset, IMEI, etc.) _prior_ to clean installing, as the CPU drivers must be installed prior to any other software, drivers, or Windows Updates _(these are the only OEM drivers Windows will not automatically install via Windows Update)_.

Answer (score 1):

If you updated to a licensed version of Windows 10 on that PC in the past, it's likely that computer would automatically activate if you installed Windows 10 on it again, through a digital license. I'm not absolutely certain of the mechanics behind this, but it's worked for me every time I've ever had to reinstall Windows 10 on any machine, even custom built ones.

When you first installed Windows 10, it collected information on your PC, and sent that to Microsoft and associated a digital license with that PC. When you reinstall, it should pull that same information and Microsoft's servers will see that you have a valid license.

Worst-case scenario, the machine won't activate. In that case, you won't be able to do some personalization options and there will be a watermark on your screen saying to activate. Unlike past versions of Windows, Windows 10 doesn't completely lock you out if you don't activate.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way for me to recover my license and know if it still valid?

There isn't anything to recover.  Your Windows 8 license key is stored in the ACPI table and is accessible by the Windows installation environment.

> I was told by some nerds that, probably, the key would be in the BIOS

You were told bad information.  The Windows license key is not stored in the BIOS.

> I would probably have to install Windows 8 and just then wait for Microsoft to ask me to update to Windows 10, correctly?

You absolutely are not required to install Windows 8 and wait for it to upgrade to Windows 10.  You would simply install Windows 10 and it would automatically activate.  When prompted for the product key you would simply skip that step.

> But how would Microsoft know I have a license?

Your machine has a digital entitlement for Windows 10.  Once you install Windows 10 on your machine, provided it's the proper edition of Windows 10, it will automatically activate.

Comment: @Michael - ACPI isn’t BIOS/UEFI

Comment: @Michael - I never said it was stored in the BIOS.  In fact I said whoever said that was actually wrong,

Answer (score 0):

You upgraded to Windows 10 on the Windows 8 machine and it was running.  So even though you change to Ubunutu, you can still go back and install Windows 10. The license is in the Microsoft Licensing Server and will work on the same computer. You need this instead of the key in the BIOS, if it is still there.

I reinstalled Windows 10 on my own X230 that had come with Windows 8 / 8.1 and then later upgraded to Windows 10. At a point some time after this, I completely reinstalled Windows 10 on this test machine and it activated just fine.

Answer (score 0):

@Sam Forbis's answer is quite right. As far as I know, Microsoft Windows 10 stores digital entitlement information in the  Microsoft Account being used to log in to the machine. 
So if now you install windows 10 then it should be able to pick up the digital entitlement license after you log in with the previously used microsoft account. That is, assuming that :

1. Previously you logged on using Microsoft Account when Windows 10 were still installed,
2. You currently have access to that account

Reading microsoft's current website, you might don't even need  the microsoft account requirement in the current windows 10 versions. They said:

> If you activated a free upgrade to Windows 10 or bought and activated Windows 10 from the Microsoft Store, you'll have a digital license for your device instead of a product key. This means you can reinstall the same edition of Windows 10 that your device has a digital license for without entering a product key.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12440/windows-10-activate

And, please note that you must use the same edition. Mixing Windows 10 SL license with Windows 10 Pro installation will not work.

A few years ago I experienced having to reactivate windows 10 because of hardware (motherboard) changes. The Windows 10 were a free upgrade from previously installed Windows 7. Because the hardware no longer match, the digital license also no longer valid. I contacted Microsoft's support, which helped me to re-activate it using Windows 7 product key (which are surprisingly already stored in the registry). So if something goes wrong after reinstalling you could try contacting Microsoft Support.